# Displaying specific fields in the datagrid from a MySQL search result in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagrid

I design (PHP) db editors in the gaming world as a past time. I took up the challenge of doing the same thing, but this time with VB (originally 6, but MySQL is tricky) so I'm working with 2008.

One of the tables has a massive amount of info and I only need to display 4 or 5 fields from it as a search result (there are over 100+ fields)

I know how to populate the grid with the whole table, but do not know how to do it via specific fields without going into a very long way around it.

This is my first time from VB6 to VB.NET - sadly not too impressed (looks like they (M$) have deviated from "BASIC" and went for the C++ engine format - super ugly (but I digress).

```
Try
    conn.Open()

    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlQRY, conn)


    Dim cb As MySqlCommandBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)


    da.Fill(ds, "big_table")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "big_table"

    Catch ex As Common.DbException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally

    conn.Close()
End Try
```

The above works fine, but I do not not need all 100+ fields displaying. Just want player name, level, if they are online and a few other fields to show - from here I can select a row and process the data elsewhere in the program.

Hope that made sense :-)

edit:
clarification: I need to know how, at run time, to create the datagrid to accept the results of my query so it does NOT display the whole record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible you specify all fields in your query with a `*`? Just declare `sqlQRY` like:

```
SELECT Player_Name, Level, Online_Status, A_Few_Other_Fields FROM Players;
```

Comment: Yup, figured that out last night. in php you can store all of it in an array and use as needed, but looks like vb handles it a little differently. so the above string works ideal!

Comment: Yes, it's going to streamline your process a lot too. PHP might allow you to pick and choose after its equivalent of binding, but that means it has sent all the data from MySQL to the engine, only to select a few.